# python: many to many groupings using iterator module

Tags: python, iterator

I have an iterable, items of which map to multiple groups. How do I group the items using an iterator module?

```
animals = (human, frog, giraffe, fish)
```

Here  human, frog, etc are objects with attributes: is_land_dwelling and is_water_dwelling.

I want to group animals based on these attributes

```
groupings = dwelling_classifier(animals)
```

should return some group iterator which splits animals into

```
is_land_dwelling: human, frog, giraffe
is_water_dwelling: frog, fish
```

I would prefer to make only single pass over the iterable. So, apart from writing my custom iterator function, is there any other way?

Comment: Can you give a bit more detail? This is very sketchy

Comment: @Jakob, I have modified the example to be clearer.

Comment: So each "classify" returns several classes?

Comment: @Eli, my example is not great. human, frog are not classes there, just simple objects. dwelling_classifier is just like iterator.groupby except that instead of classifying an item into only one group, it puts it into multiple groups.

Comment: see my updated answer. There is no such builtin in Python/stdlib that I know of, but it's easy to implement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def is_water_dwelling(animal):
    return animal in ('frog', 'fish')


def is_land_dwelling(animal):
    return animal in ('frog', 'human', 'giraffe')

animals = ('human', 'frog', 'fish', 'giraffe')

land_dwelling = (x for x in animals if is_land_dwelling(x))
water_dwelling = (x for x in animals if is_water_dwelling(x))

print list(land_dwelling)
print list(water_dwelling)
```

Note that `land_dwelling` and `water_dwelling` are generators.

This can be generalized for any amount of "classifiers", by holding the relevant classification functions in a dictionary of some kind, possibly keyed by classification type. Something like this (not tested):

```
kinds = {'water': is_water_dwelling, 'land': is_land_dwelling, 'air': is_flying}
result = {}

for kind, classifier in kinds.iteritems():
  result[kind] = [x for x in animals if classifier(x)]

# If you just want to go over animals once, you can do this instead:
from collections import defaultdict
result = defaultdict(list)

for x in animals:
  for kind, classifier in kinds.iteritems():
    if classifier(x):
      result[kind].append(x)
```

Comment: my problem is an item belongs to multiple groups. So, groupby iterator will not work as it is. With reference to your example, my item is both False and True. So, it belongs to both groups.

Comment: your answer is great. I would prefer to make single pass over the iterable. I will update the question accordingly.

Comment: @Salil: if you want a single pass over the iterable, you'll have to go over all classifiers for each `x`, so it's a simple variation on this approach - updated answer

Comment: thanks for your answer. a custom iterator using defaultdict is a good approach.